# Accessing protected resource from authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-security, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I have a scenario where the authorization server needs to access a protected resource (on a separate resource server) needs to be accessed by  for user related information. To access this protected resource, an access token is required. I generated this token manually by `TokenGranter` and added it in the header of the request made by Rest Template. When the resource is accessed it authenticates the token with the authorization server.

My problem is even though the access token generated in present in the database, I keep getting access denied when I try to access the resource.

Am I doing something wrong in accessing the resource ? How to access a protected resource from authorization server?

Below is the code used in authorization rest controller to request the resource:

```
private final OAuth2TokenGranter tg;
TokenRequest tr = new TokenRequest(reqparams, clientId, scope, grantType);

OAuth2AccessToken grantToken = tg.grant("bearer", tr);

String token = "Bearer " + grantToken.getValue();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", token);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, PagedResources.class,  authentication.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things could be wrong. First, check to see what the resource server requires the access token to have -- what scopes it needs, etc. Make sure to generate the access token with the correct scopes. You also mentioned that you need an access token to access user resource. I'm not familiar with the OAuth2TokenGranter you're using, but check that the access token generated is linked to a user authorization. Your token granter may have generated the access token, but if it's not linked to a user authorization, your authorization server will reply to the resource server's inquiry with incomplete information -- resulting to your resource server denying your request access.